# How do I link a url with an IP?

Tags: web, dns

I'm sure this is a really dumb question, but I've got a registered url (from register.com) and a server with an elastic IP (EC2 instance from Amazon), and I want to link the two. I know DNS servers are somehow involved, but I don't quite know how to fully link the two.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow [this](http://help.register.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1282/~/hosting---change-an-existing-domain%27s-ip-address-to-register.com%E2%80%99s-hosting-ip) instructions from register.com, which basically explains you how to set up an `A record` for your domain.

Comment: Well, this answer is specifically referring to addressing it to register.com's hosting services, which I'm not using. Can I just replace the IP they give with the IP I'm using?

Comment: @RiverTam Follow this then: http://help.register.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1102/~/how-do-i-change-my-ip-address%3F

Answer (score 0):

you need to setup an account with someone like zoneedit.com to link the two...or find something with a DNS registry so you can bind the 'name' with the 'ip'

However you do this with will then put that record into their nameservers and it will percolate out.